# Distinct Values in Dictionary<TKey,TValue>

Tags: c#, .net, linq, distinct

I'm trying to loop over distinct values over a dictionary list:

So I have a dictionary of key value pairs .

How do I get just the distinct values of string keys from the dictionary list?

Comment: Do you mean distinct values?  If so, Randolpho's solution is correct.

Comment: JerryB: there's no such thing as a C# Dictionary. It's a .NET Dictionary.

Comment: @JerryB: That's an awfully pedantic distinction -- and coming from me, that's saying something! C# and .NET go hand-in-hand. Using them interchangably is not doing a disservice to VB, F# and IronPython.

Comment: @Randolpho:  think you meant to reply to John Saunders here, not JerryB.

Comment: @Steven Sudit: I think you're right. :)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

```
var distinctList = mydict.Values.Distinct().ToList();
```

Alternatively, you don't need to call ToList():

```
foreach(var value in mydict.Values.Distinct())
{
  // deal with it. 
}
```

**Edit:** I misread your question and thought you wanted distinct values from the dictionary. The above code provides that.

Keys are automatically distinct. So just use

```
foreach(var key in mydict.Keys)
{
  // deal with it
}
```

Comment: This seems to be the closest to what JerryB might be intending to ask.

Answer (score 11):

Keys are distinct in a dictionary. *By definition*.

So **myDict.Keys** is a distinct list of keys.

Comment: Crap! I totally misread the question. I thought he wanted distinct values.

Comment: The question is a bit confusing. "distinct values of string keys" ?

Comment: JerryB asked "How do I get just the distinct values of string KEYS"

Comment: @Philippe Leybaert: I agree; a misleading question. I guess the author will have to show up and let us know what he really meant. Either way, +1 for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Looping over distinct keys and doing something with each value...

```
foreach( dictionary.Keys )
{
    // your code
}
```

If you're using C# 3.0 and have access to LINQ:

Just fetching the set of distinct values:

```
// you may need to pass Distinct an IEqualityComparer<TSource>
// if default equality semantics are not appropriate...
foreach( dictionary.Values.Distinct() )
{
}
```

Comment: Dictionary keys are already guaranteed distinct.  No need for the LINQ call.

Comment: @Reed: Ok, but the LINQ is only being used to make values unique, not keys.

Answer (score 0):

If the dictionary is defined as:

```
Dictionary<string,MyType> theDictionary =  ...
```

Then you can just use

```
var distinctKeys = theDictionary.Keys;
```

This uses the [Dictionary.Keys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yt2fy5zk.aspx) property.  If you need a list, you can use:

```
var dictionaryKeysAsList = theDictionary.Keys.ToList();
```

Since it's a dictionary, the keys will already be distinct.

If you're trying to find all of the distinct values (as opposed to keys - it wasn't clear in the question) in the dictionary, you could use:

```
var distinctDictionaryValues = theDictionary.Values.Distinct(); // .ToList();
```