# How to use .Distinct() in List in Dictionary? C#

Tags: c#

I have `Dictionary<string, List<string>>` and I would like to use `.Distinct()` to remove the duplicated values from the List.
How can I do that?

Comment: The keys in the dictionary are already distinct. Can you be more specific, with some example code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155410/distinct-values-in-dictionarytkey-tvalue

Comment: Are you trying to remove duplicate values from the dictionary?

Comment: Yes I'm trying to remove duplicate values from the list in the dictionary

Comment: you can use `HashSet<T>` instead of `List<T>` for distinct values

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Distinct Values in Dictionary<TKey,TValue>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155410/distinct-values-in-dictionarytkey-tvalue)

Comment: Please provide some pseudo code with an example of the desired output. We don't know if you want distinct KeyValuePairs by Value, or if you just want a List of the distinct Values (the latter being a duplicate question).

Comment: Do you want to modify each `List<string>` such that duplicates are removed? Or are you OK with substituting each `List<string>` with a ___new___ `List<string>` that does not have the duplicates? You could do something like `foreach (var kvp in yourDict.ToList()) { yourDict[kvp.Key] = kvp.Value.Distinct().ToList(); }` in the latter case.

Comment: Are you looking for this? `dic = dic.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value.Distinct().ToList());`

Comment: @Enigmativity Yeah, that is a good one if he is happy with building a new `Dictionary<,>` and assigning it to the same variable.

Comment: @Enigmativity Thank you so much this is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You can build a new `Dictionary` from the values you have

```
var n_dict = new Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<int>>();

foreach(string key in d.Keys)
{
    n_dict[key] = d[key].Distinct().ToArray();
}
```

Following the suggestions in comments from @Jeppe Stig Nielsen and @Enigmativity, you can also do

```
var n_dict = new Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<int>>(d.Count);
```

or even a one-liner

```
d = d.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value.Distinct().ToList());
```

Comment: It seems wasteful to first use `d` in the initialization of `n_dict` (first code line).

Comment: If you want any optimization, you can do `var n_dict = new Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<int>>(d.Count);` instead, to set the right capacity from the start. Otherwise, to create a new `Dictionary<,>`, the code from Enigmativity in a comment to the question, `d = d.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value.Distinct().ToList());` is easier.